# PhoneGap AJAX request not working

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using latest PhoneGap version, and doing ajax calls.

```
$.ajax({
            type      : 'POST',
            url       : 'http://example.com/path to my API', 
            data      : {d1: v1, d2: v2},
            dataType  : 'json',
            success   : function(data) {
                           console.log(data);
                        },
            error     : function(){
                            alert('Error');
                        }
});
```

When I test my app on desktop browser or mobile PhoneGap Developer App, it works fine, but after building application (.apk), ajax requests do not work and fall on failure rather than success. I have done all the configurations mentioned which include:

```
<access origin="*" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Also added Content-Security-Policy meta tags in my HTML and pointed to domain where my API is located:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self' http://example.com/">
```

I am using PhoneGap online build service to build app.
I really need help as I have done all the fixes which I could find but no success yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nabeel,
your are in luck. I am currently finishing up a [blog post on `whitelist`](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Change your CSP as follow. It should do the trick

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
          content="default-src *; 
                   style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                   script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

If you are working with iOS9, you'll need to add something for Apple's `ATS`. Read further on the document to get details on that.

Best of Luck

Comment: I removed my above mentioned CSP, and added yours. But still the same issue. Working fine on browser and PhoneGap Developer App, but not working after building .apk and running app. Ajax requests still fall on failure. Kindly help.

Comment: PhoneGap sample config had <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />. So I had the same line in my config.xml. Changing it to <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"> solved issue for me.

Comment: @Nabeel, there is no mention anywhere in you question that you are using *Phonegap Build*. Please read [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)